# Calling an array element inside another array

Tags: php, arrays

I think this is a naive question, but I can't find the proper syntax.

I have this code:

```
for ($i=1; $i<count($MyArray1); $i++){
    $element=$MyArray1[$i];
    $foo = $AnotherArray[$element];
    echo $foo;
}
```

How can I skip the second line? I mean, the third line to be something like

```
$foo = $AnotherArray[$MyArray1[$i]];
```

Comment: Yes, exactly like that.

Comment: But i think your "for" should start with 0

Comment: Nice job! answered your own question.

Comment: @pbaldauf why array push ?!

Comment: ok, thanks a lot! So I must have another problem with the arrays elements, cause the solution is not working. So, your confirmation is helpful for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for ($i=1; $i<count($MyArray1); $i++){
    echo $AnotherArray[$MyArray1[$i]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can skip a fair amount of that code to make it a bit clearer. Firstly use foreach instead of for as it's a much more reliable way of iterating over arrays. Secondly I've broken down what you're trying to do, to simplify how you're getting it. Basically using the values of one array as the keys of another. So how to do it in three lines:

```
foreach(array_intersect_key($AnotherArray, array_flip($MyArray1)) as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

This is using the excellent [array_intersect_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) method to grab all of the values from `$AnotherArray` with keys that match in the other array. As you want to use the values, we use [array_flip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) to swap the keys and values, then just loop over the result and echo it.